Injecting input fields into existing HTML Form
Im trying to make a form which will be adding a new inputs whenever the user fill another input. I set up an event listener that will do ajax request into my back-end and, if succeed, it will bring an element of input that will be injected into the form. it looked like this :
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "{% url 'cart:get-delivery' %}",
                data :{
                    city : id
                },
                success: function(res) {
                    $("#delivery").replaceWith(res.component)
                    $('.spinner-overlay').remove();
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log("Failed")
                    $('.spinner-overlay').remove();
                }
            })

the form works on the surface, but when I submit the form, it won't recognize my newly added input fields. so when I do request.POST.get('example') it won't appear. does anyone have solution on this? also here is the added element :
{% load humanize %}
{% if content %}
<td id="delivery">
    {% for ins in content %}
        {% for jenis in ins.costs %}
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio-delivery" id="{{ins.code}}" value="{{jenis.cost.0.value}}|{{ins.code}}|{{jenis.service}}">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-delivery">
            <strong>{{ins.code | upper}}</strong> - {{jenis.service}} : Rp {{jenis.cost.0.value | intcomma}}
            </label>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</td>
{% endif %}


Where in the code is it not recognizing the new inputs? Is the django the problem? If not, it would be more helpful to post the rendered html.

I fixed it. I did some tweakin and moved the  tag outside some divs and it worked. I still don't understand the nature behind this

But in your form, there is no example, only radio-delivery?
